# Preg_split & Regex - Removing brackets, text and colons

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am trying to understand how to split a string using a regex and preg_split, but I can't seem to understand the explanations online.
Especially the selector for the brackets seems to be impossible to create.

I am trying to do 2 different kinds of splits. Examples below:

1. `"[group:text]" -> "text"`
2. `"icon_type:[search]:[asterisk]" 
    -> array of 3 variables: [0]->"icon_type"
                             [1]->"search"
                             [2]->"asterisk"`

What are the two regex's to do this?

Ive tried the following for example 1: `/\[(group:)\]/`, sadly this removes nothing.

Comment: I suspect you're going to get some down-votes unless you provide an example of what you've tried. Also, can you clarify if you want to perform both matches in one regex? Or are you looking for two separate regexes?

Comment: Duplicate question removed

Comment: This looks like a normal regex match, not a split.

Comment: Could you explain to me what I need to do then, to remove the symbols + text and get the output I desire?

Comment: @Abayob No, I don't use PHP.

Comment: Not tested but as a starting point this should work for the example 1: `/\[group:(?<group>\w+)\]/`. If you use this with `preg_match($regex, $str, $matches)` the array of matches will contain a `group` key containing the string `text`; i.e: `$matches['group']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than split it is easier to use matching. Use `preg_match_all` using this regex:

```
\b\w+(?=[:\]](?![^\]\[]*\]))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yA3gQ3/1)

**Code:**

```
$re = '/\b\w+(?=[:\]](?![^\]\[]*\]))/'; 
$str = "[group:text]\nicon_type:[search]:[asterisk]"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

This regex matches a word using `\w+` which must be followed by `:` or `]` using positive lookahead assertion `(?=[:\]])` but it must also be not followed by 0 or more non-`[]` characters and `]` using negative lookahead assertion `(?![^\]\[]*\])`.